# Command for printing IP address in Ubuntu not understood

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ip, command-line-interface

It is the first time I use a Linux distribution and I find --help very difficult to use in order to unserstand the following command:

```
ifconfig eth0 | grep inet | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

Someone to explain to me please what the words of this command do? what is the name of `|` in english? 
Thanks

Comment: Hint: try "man ifconfig" for starters. Basically this little snippet lists all lines from your ethernet connection that contain the string "inet" to then print the second word (probably the ip address) from those lines. But this only prints **one** address from the first ethernet connection ... so keep in mind that a real server can have **many more** other IPs.

Comment: Yes, the `|` character creates a pipe from one command to the next one. But that is really super basic stuff that is documented out there a zillion times.

Comment: Well, that was my first thought. But probably that can be debated.

Comment: Again thanks @Jägermeister

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `|` sign called [pipeline](http://ryanstutorials.net/linuxtutorial/piping.php) and it is an operator that sends the output of the command in it left side as the input of the command in it right side.

So basicly, you have 3 commands:

```
ifconfig eth0
```

which outputs many details on your network, then you send that output to:

```
grep inet
```

which takes only the lines that contain the word `inet` and send that to:

```
awk '{ print $2 }'
```

which print the just seconed word.

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers type just `ifconfig` and you will see all the devices details.

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers As said: start with "man ifconfig" ... and run ifconfig without any parameter. Really: try to find some joy in **exploring** and making experiments. You learn those things by trying, not by asking for explanations.